# When did rules change for hyphenation

Tags: rules

When did the rules change for hyphenating the word "service." It should be hyphenated after the v. example: serv - ice.

Comment: What makes you think any rule has changed? Do you have any examples to evidence that there was a previous rule that _service_ should be hyphenated before the v?

Comment: @Janus: [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=serv-ice%2Cser-vice&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cserv%20-%20ice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cser%20-%20vice%3B%2Cc0) seems to suggest that (presumably when forced by a line-break) ***ser-vice*** was by far the dominant hyphenation in C19, but throughout C20 it's been much more of a 50-50 split, with ***serv-ice*** sometimes being marginally more common..

Comment: Line breaks occur between syllables.  And a given spelling may have several pronunciations, with different syllablizations.

Answer (score 2):

The rule has always been to split words at the boundary between syllables. *Service* consists of the syllables 'ser' and 'vice' (Oxford, Cambridge and Merriam-Webster all agree on that), so it's always been correct to divide it as 'ser-vice'.

Depending on the style guides of particular publications, it might also be acceptable to divide it as 'serv-ice', but that doesn't conform to the standard rules.